# activate elements separately on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Three elements need to be activated when hovered. These elements are also used in different divs and share the same elements and classes. I am using JavaScript to achieve this.

The problem is when hovering over div 1, it also activates div 2 and 3. Probably because they share the same elements.

How can I activate them individually when hovering?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".link")
    .hover(

      function() {
        $(".link").css('color', 'red', 'text-decoration', 'none');
        $(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #183c94');
        $("span").css('opacity', '1');
      },

      function() {
        $("link").css('color', '#000000');
        $(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #cfcfcf');
        $("span").css('opacity', '0');
      });
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  height: 10px widtth: 10px;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h4><a class="link" href="#">hover</a><span>+</span></h4>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h4><a class="link" href="#">hover</a><span>+</span></h4>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h4><a class="link" href="#">hover</a><span>+</span></h4>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73rew8su/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` to "find" the elements:

```
$(function () {
    $(".link")
    .hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css('color', 'red', 'text-decoration', 'none');
            $(this).closest(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #183c94');
            $(this).next("span").css('opacity', '1');
        },

        function () {
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
            $(this).closest(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #cfcfcf');
            $(this).next("span").css('opacity', '0');
        });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/73rew8su/3/)

Also in CSS:

```
span {
  height: 10px widtth: 10px;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}
```

Should be:

```
span {
    height:10px; width:10px;
    background: #c3c3c3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery **$(this)** key word

```
$(function () {
    $(".link").hover(function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'red', 'text-decoration', 'none');
        $(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #183c94');
        $("span").css('opacity', '1');
},

function () {
    $(this).css('color', '#000000');
    $(".box").css('border-bottom', '4px solid #cfcfcf');
    $("span").css('opacity', '0');
   });
});
```

I updated your fiddle I didnt know how you handle box or span elements on hover.